# Unable to install Android SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation, components

So I have been having a lot of problems with Android Studio, and I have just deleted and reinstalled it. I tried to setup Android Studio with the setup wizard but I am not able to download the components. Any idea on whats wrong? Might be something to do with the file path, not sure though.

[image]

And here is where it says that an error occurred.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, try installing without the Android virtual device checked, This worked for me but it was also on a different computer so it might not have been that but it's worth a crack :) Best of luck